# What does it mean to Maynard an SCV?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

What does it mean to Maynard an SCV in StarCraft or StarCraft 2.  It comes up a lot in the casts.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary was clearly not the place to broaden my knowledge. Ew.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To quote [Artosis](http://www.gosugamers.net/starcraft/thread/147114/reply_with_quote/147138)

> Maynard was a pro SC player from USA right when the game came out. He popularized over producing workers in your bases and doing what was called a "Maynard Transfer" each time he expanded by sending 12 scv/probe to the new base. This was shortened to maynard.

Comment: I actually didn't know the etymology until you just asked.  Its pretty obvious that people are using it as a transfer, but I had forgotten Maynard used to be a player, and I never even knew that hey coined the vernacular.